# How do I use a collection of individual cells instead of a range in a =lookup formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, lookup

How do I modify this formula to work with information from cells 'AT4,AX4,BB4,BF4,BJ4,BN4' instead of the range 'AT4:BN4'

```
=lookup(1,ArrayFormula(1/(AT4:BN4<>"")),AT4:BN4)
```

In this linked spreadsheet, I only want the last exit price to automatically show in cell BS4, not the last cell value in the entire range.
[google sheet spreadsheet example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DQlnI7g0DCKNm-3ywUq4ARCeGuMQOvlf1-zhwfUs0uc/edit?usp=sharing)

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: In your real sheet and application, will you be trying to find the Col BS "Price" for *just one row*, or for *all rows from Row 4 downward*?

Comment: Hi, yes, I was planning on just filling down for all the other rows going down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a new sheet ("Erik Help"). It's a duplicate of your original sample sheet.

Since you are really wanting to find the last "Price" per row for any number of rows, I used an array formula in BS4 that will accomplish this:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(AS4:AS="",,1*REGEXEXTRACT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF((RIGHT(AT$3:BN$3,5)<>"Price")+(AT4:BN=""),,"~"&AT4:BN)),,COLUMNS(AT:BN))),"~([^~]+)$")))`

Essentially, this will *smash* together each existing "Price" in a row (as determined by the word "Price" at the end of Row 3) prefaced by a tilde, forming one string, e.g.,

~9.5 ~11.5 ~13.5 ~10.65

That *smash* is accomplished with this:

`TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE([row information here]),,COLUMNS(AT:BN)))`

Then `REGEXEXTRACT` will find the last tilde in the list and extract whatever is after it. The `1*` will convert that to a number.

Comment: Thank you Eric. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: You're welcome!